# Array by Reference vs Array by Value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object

I'm reading Data Structures and Algorithms with Javascript by O'reily and it states the following:

Shallow copy (two arrays point to the same location in memory):

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
nums[i] = i+1;
}
var samenums = nums;
nums[0] = 400;
print(samenums[0]); // displays 400
```

Deep copy:

```
function copy(arr1, arr2) {
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
arr2[i] = arr1[i];
}
}
```

Now the following code fragment produces the expected result:

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
nums[i] = i+1;
}
var samenums = [];
copy(nums, samenums);
nums[0] = 400;
print(samenums[0]); // displays 1
```

Why is a function required in order to create deep copies?

Comment: `Why is a function required in order to create deep copies?` - because that is how javascript works, to change it would break the web

Comment: the function is not required, it's just esthetics and reusability

Comment: It's not really two arrays. Your "shallow copy" isn't really a copy at all. Instead of "*two arrays pointing to the same location in memory*", we talk of *two variables pointing to (or: holding) the same array*. You can create a new array explicitly if you want one, e.g. via `.slice()` or your `copy([], …)` function.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, the function is purely for aesthetics and reusability, and is not strictly necessary.

You could refactor your example:

```
function copy(arr1, arr2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i) {
        arr2[i] = arr1[i];
    }
}

var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    nums[i] = i+1;
}
var samenums = [];
copy(nums, samenums);
nums[0] = 400;
print(samenums[0]); // displays 1
```

into this equivalent function-less example:

```
var nums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    nums[i] = i+1;
}
var samenums = [];
for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
    samenums[i] = nums[i];
}
nums[0] = 400;
print(samenums[0]); // displays 1
```